# Set the length of displayed line number

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My editor display line numbers as below:

[image]

They are not aligned in columns.

How could change it's initial length from 4 to 5?

Comment: What do you use to display line numbers? Emacs does not do that by default, and there were various implementations of line-number modes. There is now a built-in line-number mode that AFAICT displays them right-adjusted based on the largest width.